# My dos batch file is not setting the output correctly

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

If my `download.txt` file has 1 or numerous items in its list, separated by a comma.  However, when I execute this command, my output is `test,abc,cat,dog`.  I need it to loop and my output should be `test` and then the next one should be `abc`, etc...

download.txt = test,abc,cat,dog

My command line is...

```
FOR /F "tokens=* eol=, delims=" %%f in (Download.txt) do set output=%%f
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (download.txt) do for %%b in (%%a) do echo %%b
```

For the data in the question, read the lines with a `for /f` loop and iterate over the elements in the line (comma is a separator) with a `for` loop

**edited** to adapt to comments

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /f "delims=" %%a in (download.txt) do (
        set "line=%%a"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        for /f "delims=" %%b in ("!line:,=","!") do (
            endlocal 
            for %%c in ("%%~b") do call mysecondfile.cmd "%%~c"
        )
    )
```

The basic idea is to enclose the full readed line in quotes (`"aaa,bb bb,ccc"`) and then replace every comma with a `","` sequence (`"aaa","bb bb","ccc"`) so we get a properly quoted sequence of elements

To be able to change a variable inside a block of code and retrieve the changed value inside the same block of code, we need delayed expansion. But with delayed expansion active, `!` characters become a problem. The `setlocal / endlocal` repetition is included to handle the presence of exclamation points in the input text.

Comment: Ok sweet that worked.  Now the next step is to take the output and use it as a variable to another batch file.  How can I do this?

Comment: Also, if one of my items in the array has a space it needs to not treat it like 2 separate items.  The delim of comma should dictate the output

Comment: @bane3977, answer updated. The easier solution is to quote the elements that include spaces (or all the elements). If this can not be done in source data, use the code added to the answer that will do the quoting while reading the input file.

Comment: Sweet.  You are the man.  One last thing and I should be finished here.  In my mysecondfile.cmd, lets say I have a simple ECHO to call the variable.  What is the syntax to retrieve the variable.  I tried %%~c, but with no success.

Comment: @bane3977, `%%c` is only visible from the code inside the `do` clause. As the data is being passed as argument to the second batch file, it will be the first argument, that is, `%1`, or `%~1` to remove the quotes